# Sending mail from own smtp server

Tags: php, email, iis, smtp

I am working for a client who bought a server (V-Server from Strato) with IIS. I've set up a SMTP Server so I can use "mail()" from php to send mails. But everytime I am trying to send a mail, it tells me to configure my SMTP server.

I already added realys, new domains and restarted the whole thing. What can I do? I want to send them from the localhost because the server is running on the machine itself.

Comment: Did you install the IIS SMTP server? It's an "add-on" that comes with IIS but usually isn't already installed.

Comment: What is the name of your *SMTP* server?

Comment: Yes, I installed the addon. The name of the strato online stmp is stmp.strato.de but the name of my virtual smtp server on the machine is "Virtual SMTP Server #1".

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to check your mail server (SMTP Server) to confirm it is working properly. To check it manually try telnet 25 port of localhost and execute basic SMTP command to see if it accept mail relaying from your localhost. Microsoft has [an article on SMTP check with telnet client](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa995718(v=exchg.65).aspx), have a look if needed.

If your SMTP server is working as expected, then try debugging your php coding.

FYI: No comments privilege, had to write this as answer...